# CSV Feed importer rounds of Float values while importing

Tags: 7, feeds, importing-exporting

I am using a Feedimporter to import values like this

-122.385170161038

in to a text field. It is rounding off the value to

-122.3851702

Not sure why? Any assistance will be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: The widget for the field is text and the underlying data type float. When I enter a float into a text widget set up like that I can only enter 10 digits. I am using MySQL and should be able to accommodate double,8B.

Comment: I am using MySQL and should be able to accommodate double,8B. According to documentation that is in the range-1.7976931348623157E+308 to -2.2250738585072014E-308. However, I cannot enter a value in scientific notation. I am marking this question up one as I too want an answer. A workaround is suggested at [Increase CCK Float field length](https://www.drupal.org/node/669622)

Comment: It seems there is another issue here. I just tested on a new install of Drupal. A float set to display 10 digits after decimal does not accept 10 digits after decimal during input (it only accepts 10 characters, leading digits and decimal included) and during display it rounds the float to even less digits after the decimal.

Comment: Hi I was looking at the width of the max lenght (255) and size of the textfield(60), that made me feel it should accomodate anything that is 16 characters in lenghth. Had no clue stuff before and after the period there matters as well.